# WeightedLatLng and Collection<WeightedLatLng>

Tags: android, google-maps, heatmap, weighted

I am using the [android API for heatmap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/heatmap). I've imported the dependencies and added the heatmap code at the end of my activity.

```
List<String> temp = Arrays.asList(coordinates.get(i).split(";"));
LatLng coor = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(temp.get(1)), Double.parseDouble(temp.get(2)));

// Create a heat map tile provider, passing it the latlngs

WeightedLatLng data = new WeightedLatLng(coor, Double.parseDouble(temp.get(0)) );
mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
                //.weightedData(data) //doesn't work
                .data(coor) //doesn't work either
                .build();
    }
```

I get the following error in the weightedData line:

```
WeightedData(java.util.Collection<com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.WeightedLatLng>) in Builder cannot be applies (com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.WeightedLatLng)
```

I tried adding a cast, but that makes the app crash. I have been googling for a long time and trying all kinds of things. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Builder weightedData and data methods take as a parameter a collection:

```
weightedData(Collection<WeightedLatLng> val)
```

Try adding all your data to an ArrayList and then pass it to your builder.

```
WeightedLatLng data = new WeightedLatLng(coor, Double.parseDouble(temp.get(0)) );
ArrayList<WeightedLatLng> weightedLatLngs = new ArrayList<>();
weightedLatLngs.add(data);

mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder().weightedData(weightedLatLngs).build();
```

Ideally your heatmap should contain many weighted latlngs, so loop through your coordinates and add them all into the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you should write code like this

```
  List<String> temp = Arrays.asList(coordinates.get(i).split(";"));
    LatLng coor = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(temp.get(1)), Double.parseDouble(temp.get(2)));

        // Create a heat map tile provider, passing it the latlngs

        WeightedLatLng data = new WeightedLatLng(coor, Double.parseDouble(temp.get(0)) );
        mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder();
        mProvider.weightedData(data); 
        mProvider.data(coor); 
        mProvider = mProvider.build();
```